# Why does my Samsung refrigerator require frequent deicing?

Tags: appliances

I have a Samsung RF23HSESBSR "Twin Cooling" refrigerator that is about six years old now and I'm having to defrost around the fan many times a year - as often as every two weeks in the humid summer.  I first had this problem about 4 years in and called Sears Technicians to diagnose/repair the clicking sound and poor cooling - I didn't yet know the basic cause and learning it cost me $250.  The tech said no parts were broken - that it just slowly built up ice over the years and shouldn't happen again for many more years.  But after a few (arid?) months, I had to do it again myself.

Internet commenters suggest that this is a shameful design flaw in these Samsungs, so I had gotten used to the idea that this otherwise excellent refrigerator would need frequent deicing.  But recently, I'm thinking back to the first four years of trouble-free operation in the same seasonal humidities and same usage and concluding that something must have broken and that I might be able to replace it and avoid the annoying deicing chore.

The fan seems to be working fine - the blades have not been damaged by the ice and as long as the ice buildup is not interfering with its operation, the refrigerator seems to operator perfectly.  Some people complain about the drain, but I never see any buildup there - it always looks exactly as pictured.
Which part needs to be replaced?

[image]

Comment: Presumably it had a frost removal cycle which is no longer functioning. This would indicate a control board problem.

Comment: Is that a dedicated control board of the defrost feature?  Otherwise I would expect other things to have broken too, no?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Just spitballing.

Comment: Defective defrost heater OR Defective control / timing (control board, or possibly sensor of some sort) of the defrost heater are the basic options, but beyond that it's hard to know (other than your appliance service folks were not very good at their job, unless their job is charging you money to do nothing useful.)

Comment: Actually Isherwood is probably correct the defrost timer or heater has probably failed. Most often it is the control. The heater is a band usually strapped to the bottom of the compressor each end has a wire when unplugged the resistance is fairly low under 50 ohms some less than 1/2 that. However I do check the heater they don’t fail as often as the controller.

Comment: Defrost timer or the drain for the defrost water being clogged.  I think you can test by manually adjusting the defrost timer and get it to cycle to the defrost mode then watch the heater work in that area.  If the water pools and doesn't drain - it is the drain.  If the heater doesn't turn on then it is the heater.

Comment: Did you verify that the door seals are still working?  If you have a leaky seal, it's possible that the continuous air exchange with humid room air is overloading the defrost system's capability.  Otherwise, follow the comments about checking drain clogs or control timing.

Comment: Thanks all.  The heater coil parts look like they’re lower on the coils.  Does the specific location of the ice buildup give any clue?  I’m not seeing a dedicated defrost control board for this model, just the heater assembly and the thermostat.  Is it integrated with the main brain of this fridge?

Comment: I replaced the themometer AND the heat coil but neither fixed the issue.  I called out another repair company through Samsung and they were more competent than earlier ones.  They pointed to moist air leaking in from the seals at the top-most pictured through-holes.  They added silicone sealant around them.  It seems better now, though I haven't opened the newly replaced cover (with its unbroken styro insulation and seals) to inspect it.  By this time, the ice maker was having build up also due to a throughhole that needed silicone sealing.  Hope this helps.